# Rails 3.1 shared client/server templates with support for i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Has anyone figured out a good solution for shared templates? I don't want to duplicate HTML between client and server. Mustache would be good except for its lack of i18n support (Twitter's contrib is js only). EJS would be perfect if its syntax was directly compatible with ERB, but not quite.

Ideally templates would live in `app/views/controller/action.html.erb` (or whatever templating lang) and a `templates.js.erb` manifest could bundle those templates up. Having a compatible syntax for a serverside render and clientside render is key to avoiding duplication.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/elado/isotope

Answer (score 1):

With [this pull request](https://github.com/creationix/haml-js/pull/39) haml-js is gaining client-side support which makes it a nice candidate for solving my issue. I will investigate further and see if it meets my needs.

Comment: Turns out to be a little awkward since the JS implementation is not fully compatible with the ruby (sort of defeating the whole purpose). Still searching...current idea is to render EJS serverside with ExecJS.

Comment: Did you find a proper solution yet?

Comment: Not really. Mustache is still the best bet, and now there's a JST compiler for Mustache. I haven't been working on solving this problem lately though.